# Fit data with a function that equals 0 and could not be converted to the form f(x) = x

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, lmfit

I have 2 columns and 31 rows in a pandas dataframe.
I want to plot this x,y data and fit them to a complex function with 4 parameters.
The function looks something like this.
The function has to be 0

```
# Data:
T,p = df["T"], df["p"] #31 rows

# known constants: a,b,Ta,c0,x

def c(T,v,VP,a=...,b=...,Ta=...,c0=...):
     c = c0 + a*(T-Ta) + b*t_r(T)**v/(t_r(T)**v-K(T,VP))
     return c

# t_r and K are other functions

def function(p,T,p0,v,N,VP,a,b,c0,x):
    return np.log(1-p) + p + (x*c(T,v,VP))*p**2 + (p0/N)*(R-0.5*R**3) # =0
```

I am interested in fitting the parameters N,p0,Vp

I tried to use Lmfit and changed my function to -> function(params,T,p)

```
from Lmfit import minimize, Parameters

## add Parameters 
params = Parameters() ##Class with a list of parameters

# add all constant Parameters with vary = False
params.add("a", value=...,vary=False)
...

## add variables to fit with vary = True, limits with min,max 
params.add("N",value=..., vary=True,min=0,max=...)
...


output = minimize(function,params) #Fit Results
output.params.pretty_print() #Show Results
```

Now I acquired the parameters, but I want to check if this makes sense by plot(T,p) for a more continous array, like:

```
Ts = np.linspace(10,60,1000) # x-array
ps = ...    ?                # y-array
plt.plot(Ts,ps,label="Fit")  # Plot Data
```

How could I obtain a function to calculate p for T on each point to plot it ?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: What do you mean with " complex fractions containing a,b,c,d and y ... = 0 " ?

Comment: Is it now more clear what I want to do ?
In short version: 
There is a function  f(x,b,c,d,e) = 0  which I am unable to solve for f(x) = ...x but I want to fit data to this function. What could I do ?

Comment: ...so do you need a root finding algorithm?

Comment: I need a way to fit data with a function without analytically solve the equation for my variables.

Comment: You should joint to your question an example of data (not graph but numerical).

Comment: This guy has the same problem but in mathematica [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72035/how-to-find-curve-fitting-parameters-without-an-explicit-relation-between-x-and)

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer myself.

First I wrap my function in a way that the y-value p is the first argument.
And I used lmfit parameter class as arguments. Lmfit Parameters are basically dictionaries.

```
p_solvable = lambda p,T,parameter : function(p,T,parameter["p0"],parameter["v"],...)
```

Then I solve the equation by scipy.optimize.root_scalar with the brentq method.
The brentq method needs Brackets where the signs are changing. I chose 1 as lower limit so np.log(1-p > 0) is defined and just the doubled maximum as upper limit.

```
p_max = np.max(p)

def p(T):
   P_Init = [root_scalar(p_solvable,args=(T,parameter), method="brentq", bracket=[1,p_max*2]).root for T in T]
   return P_Init
```

Now I have a function where I can input f(x) = y and fit it with lmfit or scipy curve_fit